# Oh My ZSH - Show home path instead of tilde

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

My terminal now shows
`name@host:~/path/to/some/file`
I want to change ~ to `/users/name/path/to/some/file`

The .zshrc file doesn't have PS1 and even though I tried adding one with $PWD (setting PS1 to `\u@\h:$PWD\$`) it didn't have any effect.

```
echo $PS1 prints
%{$fg[$NCOLOR]%}%n%{$reset_color%}@%{$fg[cyan]%}%m\
%{$reset_color%}:%{$fg[magenta]%}%~\
$(git_prompt_info) \
%{$fg[red]%}%(!.#.»)%{$reset_color%}
```

```
echo $PROMPT prints the same thing
%{$fg[$NCOLOR]%}%n%{$reset_color%}@%{$fg[cyan]%}%m\
%{$reset_color%}:%{$fg[magenta]%}%~\
$(git_prompt_info) \
%{$fg[red]%}%(!.#.»)%{$reset_color%}
```

Comment: “I tried adding one with $PWD it didn't have any effect.” Can you please add to your question _how_ you tried this?

Comment: The resource file should be `~/.zshrc` (note the `s`). Also, `zsh` can use `PROMPT`, not just `PS1`. And that code snippet is not setting the `PS1` variable. Try testing with something simple like `PROMPT='TESTING > '`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP notes they found error and self resolved

Comment: I didn't fix the issue, just added missing information.And yes I meant the zshrc file and I tried with PROMPT and it also didn't have any effect

Comment: You'll probably need to add even more information, since setting `PROMPT` in `~/.zshrc` is how you, well, set the prompt. What is the exact text you're using to set the `PROMPT` variable? Is it the last line? Are you re-starting the shell each time? What happens when you set the variable on the command line, e.g. with `PROMPT='TEST > '`?

Comment: @MarlonRichert I appreciate the advice. I know how the site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```bash
PROMPT='%n@%m:%d\$'
```

The `PS1` variable and the `\u` and `\h` escapes are from `bash`, not `zsh`.

If you want to keep the colors and other parts of that very complicated `oh-my-zsh` prompt, you can use this to replace `%~` (directory with ~) with `%d` (full directory):

```bash
PROMPT=${PROMPT/\%~/%d}
```

This will go late in the `~/.zshrc` file, after calls to the `omz` code that sets the prompt and theme.

Comment: Thanks, putting the second solution at the bottom of the file worked.

Comment: “The PS1 variable [is] from bash, not zsh.” [$PS1 works in Zsh, too.](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Used-By-The-Shell).